# can we use if block in url section of jquery-ajax?

Tags: php, jquery

```
function follow_or_unfollow(following,follower,action)
{
var dataString = "following=" + following + "&follower=" + follower;
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "network.callaction.php",  
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function() 
    {
        if ( action == "following" )
        {
            $("#following").hide();
            $("#loading").html();
        }
        else if ( action == "follow" )
        {
            $("#follow").hide();
            $("#loading").html();
        }
        else { }
    },  
    success: function(response)
    {
        if ( action == "following" )
        {
            $("#loading").html('');
            $("#follow").show();

        }
        else if ( action == "follow" )
        {
            $("#loading").html('');
            $("#following").show();
        }
        else { }
    }
}); 
}
```

In this, if action is FOLLOW then different url should call and if action is UNFOLLOW then different url should be call.

So can we use if condition in URL section?

Comment: why can't you move if condition out of ajax, and then just assign evaluated action to url?

Answer (score 0):

Out side ajax call :

```
if(yourconditin){
   url = "url1.php";
}
else{
   url = "url2.php";
}
```

In ajax give it like this :

```
url: url,
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple:

```
function follow_or_unfollow(following,follower,action)
{

    var actionUrl = 'follow.callaction.php';
    if(action == 'unfollow'){
        actionUrl = 'unfollow.callaction.php';
    }

    var dataString = "following=" + following + "&follower=" + follower;

    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: actionUrl,  
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function() 
        {
            if ( action == "following" )
            {
                $("#following").hide();
                $("#loading").html();
            }
            else if ( action == "follow" )
            {
                $("#follow").hide();
                $("#loading").html();
            }
            else { }
        },  
        success: function(response)
        {
            if ( action == "following" )
            {
                $("#loading").html('');
                $("#follow").show();

            }
            else if ( action == "follow" )
            {
                $("#loading").html('');
                $("#following").show();
            }
            else { }
        }
    }); 
}
```

You could also do this:

```
var actionUrl = action + '.callaction.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

Better put condition out of AJAX and assign the variable like this.

```
if(condition) {
     var pageURL = "example.php";
} else {
     var pageURL = "example1.php";
}

$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: pageURL,
```